# Angular Constant - MEANJS

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

**Edit:** mistype in code fixed.

I'm using the MEANJS stack which, by default comes with a default.js file with some information as below:

```
module.exports = {
  app: {
    title: 'My App Title',
    description: 'My apps description',
    keywords: 'some keywords',
    googleAnalyticsTrackingID: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID || 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID',
  }
};
```

which appears in the apps template through swig template engine. For example:

```
<title>{{title}}</title>
```

prints:

```
<title>My App Title</title>
```

Changing this value also works as expected.

If however I add in my own variable it does not recognise it, so:

```
module.exports = {
  app: {
    title: 'My App Title',
    description: 'My apps description',
    keywords: 'some keywords',
    googleAnalyticsTrackingID: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID || 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID',
    new_title: 'My Apps New Title',
  }
};
```

and then changing the view to:

```
<title>{{new_title}}</title>
```

prints:

```
<title></title>
```

Are these variables registered / passed somewhere else that I have missed?

Comment: can you clear the cache and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is not recognized because despite it being defined in your config file you have to set it in express locals object.

If you access `express.js` config file, located in `/config/lib/`, you can find this code block:

```
/**
 * Initialize local variables
 */
module.exports.initLocalVariables = function (app) {
    // Setting application local variables
    app.locals.title = config.app.title;
    app.locals.description = config.app.description;
    if (config.secure && config.secure.ssl === true) {
        app.locals.secure = config.secure.ssl;
    }
    app.locals.keywords = config.app.keywords;
    app.locals.googleAnalyticsTrackingID = config.app.googleAnalyticsTrackingID;
    app.locals.facebookAppId = config.facebook.clientID;
    app.locals.jsFiles = config.files.client.js;
    app.locals.cssFiles = config.files.client.css;
    app.locals.livereload = config.livereload;
    app.locals.logo = config.logo;
    app.locals.favicon = config.favicon;
    ...
};
```

This is where it happens. In order to have your config variable available to be used in your app templates just add the line:

`app.locals.new_title = config.app.new_title;`

For more info regarding the express app locals object, you can check the official express documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals).

Answer (score 1):

It is a JSON object. You have used `=` instead of `:` in your code.

```
module.exports = {
  app: {
    title: 'My App Title',
    description: 'My apps description',
    keywords: 'some keywords',
    googleAnalyticsTrackingID: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID || 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID',
    new_title : 'My Apps New Title' //Here
  }
};
```

Comment: My mistake, the code does actually new_title : 'My Apps New Title'; edited the original question.